# Explanation of high resolution pursuit algorithm and implementation

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, signal-processing, pseudocode

Could you explain how the high resolution pursuit algorithm works in non mathematical terms. I am not able to find an easy to follow explanation. A pseudocode algorithm and example would be helpful too.